# Set a message when I use the facebook sharer.php

Tags: facebook, message, comments, facebook-sharer

I would like to fill the message input ( comment ) of my facebook share by a default text.
I can't manage to do this, and I don't find what argument to add.

For now I have this on my link, with example content :

```
<a title="Share on Facebook" onClick="window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&amp;p[title]=My title&amp;p[summary]=My symmary&amp;p[url]=http://www.google.br&amp;&amp;p[images][0]=myimage.png','sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=548,height=325');" href="javascript: void(0)">
```

I think I have to use the javascript SDK instead with FB.ui, but I have to create an application in order to have an application_id ...

Thanks for the answers

Comment: possible duplicate of [facebook share - body text](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5023602/facebook-share-body-text)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has been answered several times already here at Stackoverflow. It's been disallowed/discouraged since some time by Facebook to programatically insert text for the user comment box. There is already a default text that clearly states what this comment box is for. The idea is that this represents the user thoughts. You already have enough tools (link, caption, description, image) to present your app.